# Bypass Insecure connection in Firefox using selenium (python)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to bypass the insecure connection in firefox using selenium in Raspberry pi 2 (Raspbian PIXEL). Firefox version(45.7.0), geckodriver(0.14), selenium(3.0.2). Tried working out with following code but its not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')
driver.quit()
```

Any ideas?

Thank you